# How can I fetch particular value(data) from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data in the firebase database as shown in the below figure.

For Inserting I use, `mFirebaseInstance.getReference("bus_tracking").child("service_no").child(busId).child("lon").setValue(obj.getLatitude());`

I can't able to figure out how to retrive the same value, any suggestions will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

I want to retrieve `lat` value.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation for querying data in Realtime Database?  I suggest making an attempt based on what you see in the docs, and if you have trouble with that, post the specific code that isn't working the way you want.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Thank you, I will try this link once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve `lat` try the following :

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bus_tracking").child("service_no");
databaseReference.child(busId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot mainSnapshot) {

       String lat = mainSnapshot.child("lat").getValue(String.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     Log.d(TAG,databaseError.getMessage());

    }
});
```

Add a reference to the node `1` then attach a listener and you will be able to retrieve the value of `lat`

Comment: WoW, It works..! I can able to figure out my mistake now. Thank you so much!